# cocos2d - exclude GUI layer transformation

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

I have a game layer that should be pannable and pinchable and a GUI layer as an overlay that's excluded from the transformations. I added the pinch and pan gesture recognizer to the view and set the view.transform like so

```
view.transform= CGAffineTransformConcat(panTransformation, pinchTranslation);
```

But it actually scales/moves the GUI layer, ofcourse, as it is a layer added to that view aswell. Sure I could do the transformations the layer itself, but the touch coordinates are scaled aswell, and calculating where the user actually tapped based on scale and translation looks like a big overhead to me.

Can I somehow add a separate view and make a GUI layer it's child? Or in any other way add GUI layer that's excluded from the transformations ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question right, but I guess you can manage the GUI yourself, instead of adding it as a child. And override function visit to do GUI visit separately.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean manage GUI myself. Can you elaborate, please ?

Comment: by managing I meant retaining, and later releasing, and visiting it yourself. instead of relying on addchlid/removeChild method of CCNode.

Comment: I understand. The problem is whatever I'd draw, it'd still be translated since the view has been pinched and panned?